# Laravel/Bootstrap - Default 'auth' layout dropdown not working

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-5

I'm working on default app.blade.php auth layout and dropdown menu is not working, I must inspect element and set .dropdown-menu's display to block in order to get to Logout link.

[image: Have to manually set display to block in order to get to Logout link]

This is the whole dropdown code, all set by default.

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }}
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
```

Comment: I believe it is there in order to logout when you click the link inside dropdown menu. I don't really know why do I need a form to do the logout job as I said this is default config for laravel's auth layout, that is not the point of my question anyways

Answer (score 1):

I was missing Bootstrap's js bundle.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```